# Clicking on button shifts entire page a few pixels to the left

Tags: css

I'm trying to fix an issue where when a user clicks a button it causes the entire page to shift to the left. The issue only seems to appear when the browser is maximized.

You can try it yourself here: https://professionallyspeaking.oct.ca/exemplary.aspx

Click on the "Great Teachers- Alphabetical +" button to see the shift in action.

Comment: I don't see anything?

Comment: What do you mean you don't see anything? Is the page not loading?

Comment: You didn't create a responsive site, that is all I see. I have clicked that button many times now.

Comment: When I click, everything remains the way they are. The page is loaded. But the page doesn't move to the left.

Comment: It's because the length of the page increases and a scrollbar appears

Comment: @Dpuiatti, The page doesn't shift when I press that button as per your question above. The button just toggles a display of some contents.

Comment: Strange. @j08691 is suggesting it's due to horizontal scroll. I tried     max-width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; to no success. Did you try to click the button with the browser maximized and the developer console off?

Comment: No, I'm saying it's from the vertical scrollbar appearing on the right side of the browser from the list being shown. Setting a width on the page, or hiding the horizontal overflow won't stop that. And why would you want to? How would anyone be able to scroll down the page if you hid the scrollbar?

Comment: @j08691 thank you so much for clarifying. That's such a silly oversight on my part. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is adding a vertical scroll bar when the content height exceeds that of the browser window. It is default behaviour, but if the shift seems odd to you, the only way to "fix" it is to force the scroll bar on the `<body>` when the content doesn't fill the page, by adding the following css:

```
body{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Page was shifting due to appearance of the vertical scrollbar. Thanks to @j08691 for pointing this out. I resolved the issue by applying overflow-y: scroll to the html:

```
html {
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: In general it's not good practice to style the `html` tag, rather use `body` instead. The html represents the document itself, whereas body is the highest level display element. Struggling to find a good reference for that however...